# How to view top tweets only from account I follow?

Tags: twitter

So I want to be able to use Twitter using the "For you" section which is a bunch of top tweets but instead have it only set to account I follow now from interest/accounts I don't follow/suggest tweets etc...

No I know that the section "Following" solves this issue but that section has no "sort by top" tweets, it only shows tweets from chronological order...

Basicall how can I have twitter like reddit where it would sort by Top tweet based on only accounts I follow?

I guess the search option works but again that's not optimal.

Much thanks

I tried removing the "interests" section by unchecking all suggested interests but unfortuantely that did not fix it and they just come back anyways so its a lose case.

Tweet deck also has same issues...